# How to call element inside .css?

Tags: jquery

I have working code using:

`$(".minutes").css("transform", "rotate(189deg)");`

This rotates my minutes hand on the clock 189 degrees.

but I delcared a variable using

`var degrees = 189`

and am trying to call it like

`$(".minutes").css("transform", "rotate(degrees + "deg")");`

but it's not working. How do you do this syntax properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable into the string, check your quotes

```
$(".minutes").css("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + " deg)");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in an es6+ environment, you can use a template literal such as:

```
$(".minutes").css("transform", `rotate(${degrees}deg)`);
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is much easier on ES6. The app I needed it for isn't ES6, but this will be very helpful in the future. Thanks Lex!